# Как правильно повернуть кастомный seekBar?

Tags: java, android

На гите есть отличный [пример камтомизации](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar), с 1300 звездочками рейтинга, но я вот не нашел ни одной функции которая правильно его могла бы сделать вертикальным...

Когда я добавляю параметр

```
android:rotation="-90"
```

Он поворачивается, но при этом продолжает занимать место как будто расположен горизонтально... Если по горизонтали уменьшить место то при показе вертикальном он тоже уменьшается...

В общем пример очень крутой и очень нужно его повернуть чтоб правильно все работало, подскажите как это можно сделать? Может в какой нибудь контейнер его поставить?

Код переопределенного класса

```
public class VerticalDiscreteSeekBar extends DiscreteSeekBar {
public VerticalDiscreteSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VerticalDiscreteSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VerticalDiscreteSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

    super.onDraw(c);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".tools.TestDeleteIt">

<com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.VerticalDiscreteSeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:dsb_thumbColor="@color/color_white"
    app:dsb_indicatorColor="@color/color_white"
    app:dsb_indicatorFormatter="%03d"
      app:dsb_indicatorTextAppearance="@style/CustomFloaterTextAppearance"
    app:dsb_max="14"
    app:dsb_min="-14"
    app:dsb_progressColor="@color/ntz_color_yellow"
    app:dsb_rippleColor="@color/ntz_color_yellow"
    app:dsb_scrubberHeight="10dp"
    app:dsb_thumbSize="25dp"
    app:dsb_trackColor="@color/ntz_color_yellow"
    app:dsb_trackHeight="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

и скрин как это выглядит(вроде как показывает что там что то есть, но на самом деле ничего не отображает...)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я сам не пробовал, но похоже, нужно переопределить следующие методы следующим образом

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
} 

@Override 
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
} 

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

    super.onDraw(c);
} 

@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false; 
    } 

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);

            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: В общем я сделал так, создал новый класс унаследовал от `DiscreteSeekBar` переопределил конструкторы и вставил ваш код и в XML файле создал обьект и теперь я наконец то смогу увидеть, что теоретически форма вью отрисовалась правильно (вертикально), до этого она чтоб я не делал рисовалась горизонтально. Но самого элемента на экране превью не появляется, и при загрузке приложения тоже не появляется(( Что нужно поправить?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, покажите код класса, который в итоге получился, и разметку, где вы его используете

Comment: 1.5 часа пробовал разобраться, ничего не получается( Я добавил описание к вопросу...